# IzPack installer, Cannot find the declaration of element 'installation

Tags: java, xml, installation, izpack

I am getting this error while compiling the install.xml

```
ERROR:  'cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'installation'.'
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: cvc-elt.
1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'installation'.'
-> Fatal error :
   Error in C:\IzPack\bin\install.xml at line 2, column 29 : javax.xml.transform
.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeExcep
tion: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'installation'.
```

And my install.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<installation version="1.0">
  <info>
    <appname>Test</appname>
    <appversion>1</appversion>
  </info>
  <guiprefs width="600" height="480" resizable="no">
  </guiprefs>
  <locale>
    <langpack iso3="eng"/>
  </locale>
  <panels>
    <panel classname="ShortcutPanel"/>
  </panels>
  <packs>
    <pack name="Test" required="yes">
      <description>Description</description>
    </pack>
  </packs>
  <resources>
    <res src="shortcutSpec.xml" id="shortcutSpec.xml"/>
  </resources>
  <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll"/>
</installation>
```

I am unable compile the install.xml . What am i doing wrong ?

I am using IzPack 5.0.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wasn't clear in the docs but

moving to:

```
<izpack:installation version="5.0"
                     xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/installation"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/installation http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-installation-5.0.xsd">
```

Fixed it for me.

Comment: Found out this, Works fine now. Thanks anyway